# Getting values from multi-dimensional array too slow

Tags: java, android, arrays, performance, sqlite

Good Day, 
I've been working on an update in an android project, and came across an issue. I have to read questions from an SQLite database which i've done successfully by loading it into a multi-dimensional array as shown below in my database helper class:

```
public String getSome(int s,int t, String Table_Name){

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Table_Name;
              SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        int rows = cursor.getCount();
        int num=0;
        int col = 0;
        String[][] base = new String[rows][13]; 

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                for (col=0;col<13;++col ){
                base[num][col] = (cursor.getString(col));} 
                ++num;
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            return base[s][t];
        }



        return null;

    }
```

With that done, i read the questions as such in my question class:

```
public void database_calls(){
          setCourseTag(courseTag);
          myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());


            try {
                myDbHelper.createDataBase();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
            }

            try {
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            }catch(SQLException sqle){
                throw sqle;
            }

            String no= myDbHelper.getSome(ques,0, getCourseTag());
            String qu = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,1, getCourseTag());
            String a = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,2, getCourseTag());
            String b = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,3, getCourseTag());
            String c = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,4, getCourseTag());
            String d = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,5, getCourseTag());
            ans = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,6, getCourseTag());
            img = Integer.parseInt(myDbHelper.getSome(ques,8, getCourseTag()));
            exp = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,9, getCourseTag());
            year = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,10, getCourseTag());
            questionImage = myDbHelper.getSome(ques,11, getCourseTag());
            length = myDbHelper.getMax(getCourseTag());
        }
```

So recently, i tried to use the `year` column, (i.e, column 10) to qualify the questions chosen for each quiz session, so that the user may be able to select the questions from any year, he/she wants to attempt. In order to do this, i used a loop at the beginning of the activity to filter out only the required year past questions. Then i transferred the indices of each question to a set, `bal` , from where it is iterated and so on..

```
public void countYearQuestions(){

        for(int y = 0; y < length; ++y){
            //year = myDbHelper.getSome(y,10, getCourseTag()); 

            if (selectedYear.equals(myDbHelper.getSome(y,10, getCourseTag())))
              bal.add(y);
        }
    }
```

Here, length is the size of the entire question database, for the course, (indicated by getCourseTag()). The code works quite alright. But it takes a whole 8-9secs!! for the activity to load. Any help on how to reduce this loading time would be appreciated.

Comment: Why the array? Why don't you let the database do the filtering for you?

Comment: @CL. omg, i didn't think of that. So in essence, i can simply do the filtering from the sqlite db, in the DB helper class. I believe that should speed up the process, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're doing this is pretty efficient in slowing everything down (and your helper helps you with it a lot):

```
String no= myDbHelper.getSome(ques,0, getCourseTag());
```

In each such line you execute a query, create a 2D array holding the whole table and throw nearly everything away. *And you fail to close the `Cursor`.*

So you need 12 values from a table and read instead the whole table 12 times.

Comment: Thanks for the eye-opener, my first solution to this would be to make the `getSome()` method create a single dimension array (1D) of the required column. I believe that if i do so, the entire table won't be read 12 times, but rather, each column would, thereby making the table read only once. Am I right on this?

Comment: Tried it and as expected, everything sped up, including all question refreshes. So, any more tips on how to improve the performance, seeing as loading time is reduced to 3 seconds, which I still feel can be less.

Comment: I'd drop the helper and use a local variable for `getCourseTag` (no idea how expensive this call is). If you need all columns from a single row, that's a single query (`SELECT ... WHERE ..`) and should take a few milliseconds at most.

Comment: Really sorry, I lost you at the `(SELECT ... WHERE ..)` part, my sqlite knowledge ain't that vast. I intend on getting all rows in a single column, how can i use the sqlite commands to execute this, replacing the 1D array?

Comment: @Mofe-hendyEjegi Single column and all rows? That's strange, thing about transposing it. Anyway, you do do it with `SELECT theWantedColumnName FROM tableName` without any 2D array.

Comment: Loading time now: ~1 - 1.5secs. :) Selecting a single column from the table, and getting rid of the array did the trick. I've accomplished what I needed, thanks.